# F# MySQL Type Provider, references / packages, on Linux Monodevelop

Tags: mysql, linux, f#, monodevelop, type-providers

I'm moving a project (and database) from Windows and SQL Server and Visual Studio, over to Linux Mint, MySQL and MonoDevelop. I'm most of the way done--but I can't get the type provider for MySQL to work. The  most obvious sticking point seems to be that:

```
open FSharp.Data.Sql
```

Gives Error, the namespace of 'Sql' is not defined. (And I don't see a NuGet package for that name.)

There's no error on any of:

```
open MySql.Data    
open MySqlConnector
open FSharp.Data
```

I seem to have packages/references to:

```
MySqlConnector
MySql.Data
FSharp.Data
FSharp.Data.SqlClient
FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
```

And then I also get an error for:

```
SqlDataProvider
```

"The type 'SqlDataProvider' is not defined'".

I'm sure this is very simple, but I'm not great at which or how to use references--sorry and thanks.

(And I don't really understand how to distinguish `SQLProvider` from `FSharp.Data.Sql` provider from `MySql.Data.dll` from `MySqlConnector.dll`...)

Edits: Thanks for questions. I assume this is .Net Framework, not Core. The project originated in defaults Visual Studio templates about 3 years ago, and I've never done anything to purse Core.

For the fsproj file(s)--I'm not sure what's what. I have 4 projects in the solution (only 2 actively being used). For the project with the type provider types, this is the project.fsproj.FileListAbsolute.txt, in /obj/Debug.

```
C:/Users/gen/Desktop/Simulations/SqlFunctions/bin/Debug/Library3.XML
C:/Users/gen/Desktop/Simulations/SqlFunctions/bin/Debug/Library3.exe
C:/Users/gen/Desktop/Simulations/SqlFunctions/bin/Debug/Library3.pdb
C:/Users/gen/Desktop/Simulations/SqlFunctions/bin/Debug/FSharp.Core.dll
C:/Users/gen/Desktop/Simulations/SqlFunctions/bin/Debug/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.dll
C:/Users/gen/Desktop/Simulations/SqlFunctions/bin/Debug/FSharp.Core.xml
C:/Users/gen/Desktop/Simulations/SqlFunctions/bin/Debug/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.xml
C:/Users/gen/Desktop/Simulations/SqlFunctions/obj/Debug/Library3.exe
C:/Users/gen/Desktop/Simulations/SqlFunctions/obj/Debug/Library3.pdb
/home/gen/Downloads/Simulations 2018-07-29/SqlFunctions/bin/Debug/Library3.XML
/home/gen/Downloads/Simulations 2018-07-29/SqlFunctions/obj/Debug/SqlFunctions.fsprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache
/home/gen/Downloads/Simulations 2018-07-29/SqlFunctions/obj/Debug/Library3.exe
/home/gen/Downloads/Simulations 2018-07-29/SqlFunctions/obj/Debug/Library3.pdb
```

The top half of those look like old Windows references-? Obviously none of it includes anything like MySql.Data--which does appear in project/References/From Packages.

Oh wait, this at the solution level may be more relevant (I've never worked with .fsproj files):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>397e58f9-3730-4c45-a36f-7c9f64d94f1d</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>Simulations</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Simulations</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFSharpCoreVersion>4.4.0.0</TargetFSharpCoreVersion>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <Name>Simulations</Name>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <Tailcalls>false</Tailcalls>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <WarningLevel>3</WarningLevel>
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Debug\Simulations.XML</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <Tailcalls>true</Tailcalls>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <WarningLevel>3</WarningLevel>
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Release\Simulations.XML</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MinimumVisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(MinimumVisualStudioVersion)' == ''">11</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Choose>
    <When Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '11.0'">
      <PropertyGroup Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\..\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.0\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets')">
        <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\..\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.0\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </When>
    <Otherwise>
      <PropertyGroup Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\FSharp\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets')">
        <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\FSharp\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </Otherwise>
  </Choose>
  <Import Project="$(FSharpTargetsPath)" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="AssemblyInfo.fs" />
    <Compile Include="1a.fs" />
    <Compile Include="2a.fs" />
    <Compile Include="2b.fs" />
    <Compile Include="2c.fs" />
    <Compile Include="2d.fs" />
    <Compile Include="2e.fs" />
    <Compile Include="2f.fs" />
    <Compile Include="3a.fs" />
    <Compile Include="3b.fs" />
    <Compile Include="3c.fs" />
    <Compile Include="3d.fs" />
    <Compile Include="4a.fs" />
    <Compile Include="4b.fs" />
    <Compile Include="4c.fs" />
    <Compile Include="5a.fs" />
    <Compile Include="5b.fs" />
    <Compile Include="5c.fs" />
    <Compile Include="5d.fs" />
    <Compile Include="5e.fs" />
    <Compile Include="6a.fs" />
    <Compile Include="6b.fs" />
    <Compile Include="7a.fs" />
    <None Include="Script.fsx" />
    <None Include="packages.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="mscorlib" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
    <Reference Include="FSharp.Core">
      <HintPath>packages\FSharp.Core.4.5.2\lib\net45\FSharp.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="FSharp.Data.TypeProviders">
      <HintPath>packages\FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.5.0.0.6\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.ValueTuple">
      <HintPath>packages\System.ValueTuple.4.5.0\lib\netstandard1.0\System.ValueTuple.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="SqlFunctions\SqlFunctions.fsproj">
      <Name>SqlFunctions</Name>
      <Project>{14eefa95-3b68-4348-a7de-db29bfb3567f}</Project>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Thanks again.

Edit 2: As I comment below--the situation has progressed (I think) to: Invalid attempt to read when Reader is closed--error on the type declaration.

Comment: Possibly relevant: Is this .net framework or core?

Comment: Please show us your `.fsproj` file so we can see the package references already defined. According to [the SQLProvider documentation](https://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/core/general.html), you'll need to create a reference to the `FSharp.Data.SqlProvider.dll` file, found in the `SQLProvider` package. If we can see your `.fsproj` file, we can advise you on the best way to do it. (I recommend using [Paket](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/) for package management).

Comment: Looking now, maybe it's a problem with references in one project but not another. I have the references in the project that declares the type provider type. But now I see that I don't have all of the MySql references in the lower down project which contains the main module and entry point. I'll start trying to add references there.

Comment: I'll also mention that I'm in NuGet because that's all I see in MonoDevelop.

Comment: Once you get the references into the .fsproj, I think it should work for you. One more tool recommendation, though. I spent a while working in MonoDevelop and found it useable but a little annoying here and there. Once I tried Visual Studio Code with the Ionide plugin, it was a HUGE improvement and I immediately switched away from MonoDevelop. Give VS Code a try, and install the Ionide plugin, and see if that is a nicer experience than MonoDevelop.

Comment: @munn Thanks for the looks. Somehow MonoDevelop froze up--and the restart seems to have awakened the references. (maybe...) Aside from this freeze up, MonoDevelop crashed suddenly twice when opening files with the type providers not set up. I'll try VS Code. Hopefully it may be more stable. .But first I would like to get my stuff to compile and run one time! Then after that... Thanks again.

Comment: Well I copied some dlls around, installed some more packages (System.Memory, more FSharp.Data things, ...--hopefully there are never too many!), got by an SSL error--which all seems to be progress. But now I'm stuck at an error on the type: Invalid attempt to read when Reader is closed. And I can't find anything online in a type provider context for this error. If anyone sees this, suggestions appreciated. Thanks.